# How to use sizeof in the void function for determine size of 2d matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, function, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void find_col_num(int matrix[][5])
{
    printf("size of matrix = %d\n",sizeof(matrix));
    printf("size of one element = %d\n", sizeof(matrix[0][0]));
    printf("number of columns = %d\n", sizeof(matrix)/(sizeof(matrix[0][0])*5));
}

int main()
{
    int a[6][5] = { {0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,0,0},
                    {1,0,1,0,0},
                    {1,0,1,0,0},
                    {0,1,1,1,1} };

    find_col_num(a);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    printf("size of a = %d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("size of one element = %d\n", sizeof(a[0][0]));
    printf("number of columns = %d\n", sizeof(a)/(sizeof(a[0][0])*5));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size of matrix = 8
size of one element = 4
number of columns = 0



size of a = 120
size of one element = 4
number of columns = 6
```

I want to use `sizeof` in the void or int function for determine number of the matrix's column. I know that I have to specify number of the matrix's line in the function. How can I handle that?

Comment: The function `find_col_num` has *no way* to know the size of its argument. You have to pass that as another argument unless it is known globally. In fact it can be *any size* provided you don't exceed the array bounds. There is no size for the outer dimension given, and even if there were, that is not restrictive. The only reason for the one dimension given is so that the compiler knows *how* to index the 2D array.

Comment: well... How can I handle that? Sorry, I am new in the C.

Comment: An array passed to a function decays to a pointer, and that is what the compiler knows. If it were a 1D array that is enough information. Here it is a 2D array so the compiler needs to know the width of each row. That's why the inner dimension is given. Note that for a 1D array, even if you state the dimension, the compiler will *ignore it*. Similarly, the 2D array here has no outer dimension, because the size of the array is unlimited.

Comment: You have to pass the number of elements in the outer dimension to the function. BTW you *know* the size of the array, because you are the one who defined it. Suppose you allocate memory with `malloc`. People ask here "What is the size of the memory?" and the only possible answer is "the size you told it to allocate".

Comment: well.. How can I allocate memory again in the void function?

Answer (score 1):

The argument, `int matrix[][5]` when passed to a function, *decays* to a pointer to `int`. This is the reason why its size is 8 (the size of a pointer in your system).

As a consequence, the calculated number of columns is not what you expect.

I'm afraid there's no chance to obtain what you want without changing `find_col_num ()` signature. The best way is probably passing the total size of the matrix to the function:

```
void find_col_num(int matrix[][5], size_t tot_size)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

And you could call it in this way

```
find_col_num(a, sizeof(a));
```

Comment: Thank you :D why didn't I think of this

Comment: @ÖmerFarukVERGİSİZ you are welcome. Most solutions appear trivial... after you know them.

Comment: I am sorry now I realize that I cannot use this solution because I used the **find_col_num**  in the another function, so I can't use **sizeof** there either.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukVERGİSİZ I'm afraid you will have to change that other function as well..

Comment: if you have time, could you look my code? I will understand if you don't want to look.